# File extension renaming in R

Tags: r, text-mining, file-rename

I am just trying to change the filename extensions to .doc. I'm trying the code below but it does not work. How come? I'm using instructions from [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/programatically-rename-files-or-do-other-stuff-to-them-in-r/)

```
startingDir<-"C:/Data/SCRIPTS/R/TextMining/myData"

filez<-list.files(startingDir)

sapply(filez,FUN=function(eachPath){
  file.rename(from=eachPath,to=sub(pattern =".LOG",replacement=".DOC",eachPath))
})
```

The output I get is:

```
DD17-01.LOG DD17-02.LOG DD17-03.LOG  DD17-4.LOG  DD17-5.LOG DD37-01.LOG DD37-02.LOG DD39-01.LOG DD39-02.LOG DD39-03.LOG 
      FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is even easier. Here we start by creating 10 files (in the shell):

```
$ for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do touch file${i}.log; done
```

Then in R it is really just three *vectorized* operations:

```
files <- list.files(pattern="*.log")
newfiles <- gsub(".log$", ".doc", files)
file.rename(files, newfiles)
```

We read the filenames, do the transformation on all of them at once (replacing the trailing `.log` with `.doc`) and renamed *all* files at once from the old names to the new names.

This will echo a `TRUE` for each implicit renaming:

```
edd@max:/tmp/filerename$ Rscript renameFiles.R 
 [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
edd@max:/tmp/filerename$ ls
file0.doc  file1.doc  file2.doc  file3.doc  file4.doc  file5.doc  
file6.doc  file7.doc  file8.doc  file9.doc  renameFiles.R
edd@max:/tmp/filerename$
```

**Edit:** Here is an even more explicit walkthrough doing EVERYTHING in R:

```
edd@max:/tmp/filerename/new$ ls                    ## no files here
renameFiles.R
edd@max:/tmp/filerename/new$ cat renameFiles.R     ## code we will run

options(width=50)
ignored <- sapply(1:10, function(n) write.csv(n, file=paste0("file", n, ".log")))
files <- list.files(pattern="*.log")
print(files)

newfiles <- gsub(".log$", ".doc", files)
file.rename(files, newfiles)

files <- list.files(pattern="*.doc")
print(files)
edd@max:/tmp/filerename/new$ Rscript renameFiles.R  ## running it
 [1] "file10.log" "file1.log"  "file2.log" 
 [4] "file3.log"  "file4.log"  "file5.log" 
 [7] "file6.log"  "file7.log"  "file8.log" 
[10] "file9.log" 
 [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[10] TRUE
 [1] "file10.doc" "file1.doc"  "file2.doc" 
 [4] "file3.doc"  "file4.doc"  "file5.doc" 
 [7] "file6.doc"  "file7.doc"  "file8.doc" 
[10] "file9.doc" 
edd@max:/tmp/filerename/new$
```

Comment: Also - I don't understand the $ in the case of ".LOG$". What is its purpose?

Comment: Read documentation on regular expressions, it means _ending_ in `.log`.

Comment: Make sure that the `full.names = TRUE` within `list.files(wd,pattern = "\\.log", full.names = TRUE), otherwise the `file.rename` will not find the files and you will end with `file.rename(old, new)` as `FALSE FALSE..`

Comment: It's trivial in this scenario, but it might make a difference with other file extensions.  In the call to `gsub()`, the values `".log$"` and ".doc" could tightened up to `"\\.log$"` and `"\\.doc"`.