# R renaming file extension

Tags: r, replace, file-extension

I have tried looking at [File extension renaming in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40754689/file-extension-renaming-in-r) and using the script without any luck. My question is very much the same.

I have a bunch of files with the a file extension that I want to change. I have used the following code but cannot get the last step to work.

I know similar questions have been asked before but I'm simply stuck and therefore reaching out anyway.

```
startingDir<-"/Users/anders/Documents/Juni 2019/DATA"
endDir<-"/Users/anders/Documents/Juni 2019/DATA/formatted"

#List over files in startingDir with the extension .zipwblibcurl that I want to replace
old_files<-list.files(startingDir,pattern = "\\.zipwblibcurl")

#View(old_files)

#Renaming the file extension and making a new list i R changing the file extension from .zipwblibcurl to .zip
new_files <- gsub(".zipwblibcurl", ".zip", old_files)

#View(new_files)

#Replacing the old files in the startingDir. Eventually I would like to move them to newDir. For simplicity I have just tried as in the other post without any luck:...
file.rename( old_files, new_files)
```

After running `file.rename` I get the output FALSE for every entry.

Comment: Did you try `list.files(startingDir,pattern = "\\.zipwblibcurl", full.names = TRUE)` ? Otherwise, `list.files` only returns the file names, and `file.rename` does not find them in the current directory.

Comment: Thank you @Stéphane. That worked. I had overlooked full.names. And thank you for explaining your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The full answer here, including comment from @StephaneLaurent: make sure that you have `full.names = TRUE` inside the `list.files()`; otherwise the path to the file will not be captured, just the file name.

Full working snippet:

```
old = list.files(startingDir,
                 pattern = "\\.zipwblibcurl",
                 full.names = TRUE) #

# replace the file names
new <- gsub(".zipwblibcurl", ".zip", old )

# Rename old files names to the new file names
file.rename(old, new)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @StéphaneLaurent said, it's most likely that R tries to look in the current working directory for the files and can't find them. You can correct this by adding

`file.rename(paste(startingDir, old_files, sep = "/"), paste(newDir, new_files, sep = "/"))`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not really sure why it isn't working. I am running the script `file.rename(paste(startingDir, old_files, sep = "/"), paste(endDir, new_files, sep = "/"))` but still get false for all the entries.

Comment: That's odd. Hard to say from my side what's wrong, because it works on my end. Is it possible that there is an issue with special characters or spaces in the filename?

Comment: Not sure really. As I have indicated above, @Stephanes answer worked but your suggestion would have been great as it would also have moved the files to the new directory. I am new to coding so curious how you have decided `sep = "/"` ?