# Convert .OUT files to .CSV in R

Tags: r

I want to convert .out files to csv files in loop. The following code is not working. Please help.

```
fp <- "D:/54311/Output"  # specify file path
fl <- list.files( path = fp, pattern = ".OUT", full.names = TRUE ) 
# get .out files
for (file in fl ){  # loop through files, read it and write it as .csv files. Then 
delete .out files
flag <- tryCatch( {
write.table( x = read.table(file = file, header = TRUE ), 
             file = file.path( fp, gsub( "out$", "csv", basename( file ) ) ), 
             sep = ",", 
             row.names = FALSE )
TRUE
},
error = function( x ) { 
print( paste0( "Problem reading and writing file : ", file ) )
return(FALSE) } )
}
```

Comment: for starters the second line of the for loop needs to be commented out

Comment: How specifically is it not working? If you’re just getting `"Problem reading and writing file"`, take your code out of `tryCatch()` to get a more informative error. And what is the format of the `.out` files?

Comment: Useful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40754780/2799941

Comment: Yes, the error is "Problem reading and writing file". The file consists of 20 columns separated by a comma

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40754780/2799941 Yes, this was helpful and it worked converting OUT files to CSV. Thanks a lot.